# Guardar en una variable valor seleccionado de un select

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Queria consultar como puedo guardar el valor seleccionado de un select en una variable, para luego enviarlo al controlador. Estoy trabajando con MVC C#

VISTA

@{
    Layout = null;

}

```
<title>MESES</title>
```

```
    <form id="form1" method="post">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Selecciones mes</legend>
                        <select name="selectmes" id="mes">
                            <option value="1">Enero</option>
                            <option value="2">Febrero</option>
                            <option value="3">Marzo</option>
                            <option value="4">Abril</option>
                            <option value="5">Mayo</option>
                            <option value="6">Junio</option>
                            <option value="7">Julio</option>
                            <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                            <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
                            <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                            <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                            <option value="12">Diciembre</option>

                        </select>


                    <p>
                        <input id="BtnEnviar" name="Button1" type="submit" alue="enviar" onclick="return validar()" />
                    </p>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

de antemanos gracias

Comment: En principio debería bastarte con definir un argumento `selectmes` de tipo `int` o `string` en la acción a la que realices el post del formulario.  Sin más información no hay mucho más que te pueda decir.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: quiero guardarlo en una variable INT =(value), mi duda es como guardar el item seleccionado y como rescatarlo. seria int mes = ¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Asp MVC tenemos algo que se llamada Model Binding el cual consiste en obtener todos los elementos html con valor en una colección en una acción form post (FormCollection).

En tu caso puedes hacer algo del tipo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    int mes = Convert.ToInt32(collection["selectmes"]);
    return View();
}
```